# Event parameter gone immediately after setting

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, event, parameters

The core of my problem is this piece of code:

```
let eventOut = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
console.log('eventOut = ' + eventOut);
eventOut.setParams({
  "message": theMessage
});
console.log('complete event = ' + JSON.stringify(eventOut, null, 4));
console.log('params(1) = ' + eventOut.getParams());
console.log('params(2) = ' + JSON.stringify(eventOut.getParams(), null, 4));
console.log('message(1) = ' + eventOut.getParam("message"));
console.log('message(2) = ' + eventOut.getParams().message);
const params = eventOut.getParams();
console.log('Looping over parameters:');
for (let f in params) {
  console.log(f + ' = ' + params[f])
}
```

It produces the following output:

```
eventOut = SecureAuraEvent: [object Object]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} }
complete event = {}
params(1) = [object Object]
params(2) = {}
message(1) = undefined
message(2) = undefined
Looping over parameters:
```

I have tried `message: theMessage` in the setParams part and I have tried `eventOut.setParam("message", theMessage)`, but it doesn't make any difference.

How come my parameters are empty after setting? I have a valid event object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was trying to add a parameter with the wrong name to the event. This particular event - e.force:navigateToComponent - has several attributes, and message is not one of them.

In my naivety, and JS inexperience, I thought that I could just add any attribute/parameter to an event. But apparently that is not possible in this case and - worse - you do not get any warning or error that what you are doing is incorrect. So this acts like a fail-silent system, which is inconvenient at the least and dangerous at the most. Remember Chernobyl.